# How to display updated values in new window

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, nan

I'd like ask that when I input data into textarea, I cannot get the result in new window.
I mean, when I click the calculation button, the result displays NaN. I cannot handle how to do it. Code is below

Can anyone inform me please?

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('white');


var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({

    title : 'Welcome to BMI'
});

var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:'BMI'
});

var win3 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:'BMI'
});


var win4 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'BMI'


});
win4.addEventListener('open', function(e){

    textAreaHeight.value/textAreaWeight.value;



});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top: 100,
    text:'Welcome to BMI',
    color : 'blue',
    font: { fontSize:48 }

});






var standardButton = Ti.UI.createButton(
    {
    title:'Standart',
    top : 250,
    height:50,
    width: 200
});
    standardButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        win1.close();
        win2.open();
});



var metricButton = Ti.UI.createButton(
    {
    title:'Metric',
    top : 350,
    height: 50,
    width: 200
});
    metricButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        win1.close();
        win2.open();    
});


var labelHeight = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:'Height',
    color:'red',
    top:300,
    left:100,
    font: { fontSize:24 },
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var HeightValue = Titanium.App.Properties.getInt("HeightValue");
var textAreaHeight = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
  value : HeightValue,
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: '#bbb',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: '#888',
  font: {fontSize:20, 
  fontWeight:'bold'},

  left:200,
  top: 300,
  width: 125, 
  height : 40

  });

    textAreaHeight.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    textAreaHeight.blur();
    Titanium.App.Properties.setInt("HeightValue", e.value);

    });

var labelWeight = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Weight",
    color:'red',
    top:400,
    left:100,
    font: { fontSize:24 },
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});


var WeightValue = Titanium.App.Properties.getInt("WeightValue");
var textAreaWeight = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
  value : WeightValue,
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: '#bbb',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: '#888',
  font: {fontSize:20, 
  fontWeight:'bold'},

  left:200,
  top: 400,
  width: 125, 
  height : 40
 });

    textAreaWeight.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    textAreaWeight.blur();
    Titanium.App.Properties.setInt("WeightValue", e.value);

    });

var CalculatorButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Calculate',
    top:475,
    width:400,
    height:90,
    left:75
});

     CalculatorButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     //alert(textAreaHeight.value);
     //alert(textAreaWeight.value);

     win2.close();
     win4.open();
});



     var BMILabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:textAreaHeight.value/textAreaWeight.value,
            font:{fontSize:84},
            color:'red',
            textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
            top:100

        });

var ExitButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Exit',
    top:475,
    width:400,
    height:90,
    left:500
});
    ExitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        win2.close();
        win1.open();
    });


win2.add(ExitButton);
win2.add(CalculatorButton);
//win2.add(BMILabel);
win2.add(labelHeight);
win2.add(textAreaHeight);
win2.add(labelWeight);
win2.add(textAreaWeight);
//win4.add(textAreabmi);
win4.add(BMILabel);


win1.add(standardButton);
win1.add(metricButton);
win1.add(label1);
win1.open();
```

Comment: What you're actually trying to do? Be more specific.

Comment: I am trying to do that when user inputs their height and weight, it should calculate its BMI. 
However, in win4, I don't want to display the result as alert. I created a label for win4 and I wanna make sure the result will be displayed in label, not an alert message

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place for your home works, here others will help/guid you to resolve your issues by providing hints. Not full code. So you need to create a label, add it to window and set it's text content, instead of my alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CalculatorButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     win4._myValue = textAreaWeight.value;
     win4.open();
     win2.close();
});


win4.addEventListener('open', function(e){

    alert(win4._myValue);

});
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't help.